# Realizar subconsulta UPDATE oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

Tengo que hacer una subconsulta con la tabla HR y me pide que modifique el salario de los empleados por el máximo de su categoría profesional.

Tabla `jobs` 
[image: 1]

Tabla `employees`
[image: 2]

```
UPDATE employees
SET
    salary = (
        SELECT
            MAX(salary)
        FROM
            employees e2
        WHERE
            e2.department_id = employees.department_id
    );
```

Esto es lo que había puesto pero no me sale correctamente.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. He editado la pregunta para mostrar las imagenes dentro de ella, aunque considero que es mejor publicar la estructura y datos de las tablas como texto plano. También para darle formato de código a la sentencia publicada. Te invito a darle clic a "Editar" para ver como se hace en MarkDown. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba esta query:

```
UPDATE (SELECT 
             e.SALARY,
             j.MAX_SALARY
          FROM employees AS e
          INNER JOIN jobs AS j ON e.JOB_ID = j.JOB_ID)
   SET SALARY = MAX_SALARY;
```

Otra forma de hacerlo (como lo intentaste hacer vos):

```
UPDATE employees e 
SET SALARY = (SELECT j.MAX_SALARY
              FROM jobs j 
              WHERE e.JOB_ID = j.JOB_ID);
```

Te recomiendo siempre primero hacer un backup de los datos, de esta manera si no obtenes el resultado deseado podes volver a recuperar los datos que tenías antes de ejecutar la query.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda compañero te agradezco enormemente tu tiempo!

Comment: De nada! Me alegra haberte ayudado. Recuerda siempre seleccionar la respuesta que mejor conteste tu pregunta, así las misma que marcada como respondida. También puedes votar las diferentes respuestas.